# Enable "Change Item Order" button on ribbon

Tags: ribbon

I have a page that I'm provisioning in Visual Studio 2010 through a module.  In my elements.xml I have a `<File>` element with a `<View>` element underneath like this:

```
<File Path="TemplatePage.aspx" Url="Edit_Pages/Links.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >    
  <View List="Lists/Links" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2" />
</File>
```

The view looks at a list of links.  Everything goes fine with the provisioning but when I go to the page and click on the webpart the "Change Item Order" option under the ribbon "List Tools -> Items" is disabled.  However, if I go to the list directly through "View All Site Content", the option is enabled. My question is "How can I enable the Change Item Order button?".

[image: Change Item Order Disabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a technique to set the "Allow users to order items in this view?" property for the webpart.  I call this method from the feature receiver of my provisioning feature.  The key is setting the `XsltListViewWebPart.ViewFlags` to include `SPViewFlags.Ordered`.  Here is the [forum entry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010programming/thread/0ddca0f6-2b17-4f4a-9d66-f3d684ed4a11) answer by Porter Wang which led me to my solution.

```
SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
SPFile file = web.GetFile(pageUrl);
file.CheckOut();

SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = 
  file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

XsltListViewWebPart selectedWebPart = (XsltListViewWebPart)
  (from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts
   where webPart is XsltListViewWebPart && webPart.ZoneIndex == webPartZoneOrder
   select webPart).FirstOrDefault();

if ((selectedWebPart.ViewFlags & SPViewFlags.Ordered) == 0)
  selectedWebPart.ViewFlags = selectedWebPart.ViewFlags | SPViewFlags.Ordered;

webPartManager.SaveChanges(selectedWebPart);
web.Update();

file.CheckIn(String.Empty);
file.Publish(String.Empty);
file.Approve(String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

That option is enabled normally only on Links and Meeting Workspaces. E. Struyf has an excellent series on how to customize any list to support it here http://www.estruyf.be/blog/order-list-items-like-in-a-meeting-workspace-part-1/
For a list instance based on the TemplateType=103 (LINKS)

```
<ListInstance Title="Global Links"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="103"
                FeatureId="00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103"
                Url="GlobalLinks" RootWebOnly="TRUE"
                Description="Use this list to store links with Global scope"/>
```

Inserting a ListView while provisioning the page should be achieved like this

```
<View BaseViewID="9" List="GlobalLinks" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="1" DisplayName="Global Links" >
        <![CDATA[
          <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
              <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
              <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart</TypeName>
              <Title>My Requests</Title>
              <Toolbar>None</Toolbar>
              <NoAnnouncements>You have no links available.</NoAnnouncements>
          </WebPart>
        ]]>

      </View>
```

Comment: This IS a "Links" list.  That's why it works automatically when I go to the list from the "View All Site Content" page.  However, I'm putting the list on another page as well and I would like the user to be able to do it there.

Comment: If you use the OOTB ListView web-part in a page you should get this functionality in the Ribbon under the Items tab (as usual) - just checked (you need at least 1 item)! I've added to my answer an example of the List Instance for Links!

Comment: Sorry, I just added my xml to my question.  As you can see I'm using my own page with a view of the list in addition to the page that is automatically provisioned when you use the xml from the answer you provided.

Comment: I use the 1st bit to create a list instance which can be used in features. The 2nd part of the code, shows how you can provision via Module a page with a View embed in it (which I believe your intention is).

Comment: My example in the question also provisions via Module a page with an embedded view.  Have you tested your version to make sure that "Change Item Order" is available on that provisioned page?  I'm not meaning to be rude but I was wondering what the difference between mine and yours would be that allows yours to see that option.  When I look at the view for my webpart the "Allow users to order items in this view?" option is set to "No" after provisioning.